# Setting up URL through namecheap

Tags: url, dns, cname

i am trying to have my domain (http://musicmartian.com) route to 104.131.30.223 and currently not being particularly successful.

[Current Domain settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoQ8E.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/319/78/how-can-i-setup-an-a-address-record-for-my-domain

Here is a nice tutorial to help you along your Journey

Comment: Link-only answers are technically fine, but consider including a brief description of the information you're linking to, to help OP and others viewing this.